# Group Facebook/Twitter/GooglePlus generate SCRIPT tags together

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

You will most likely recognise the below javascripts from facebook/twitter/googleplus, all I have done here is group them nicely together.

How can I use jQuery to create the script tags and improve the code to work together?

```
function generateJs(){

    // Google Plus
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);

    // Facebook API 
     $("body").append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');          
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId="+opt.faceBookID;
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Twitter
    !function(d, s, id){
        var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
}
```

Comment: Your JS Fiddle example is working perfectly for me... All 3 "elements" load and are displayed very quickly.  What exactly are you trying to achieve beyond this?  "Don't fix something that isn't broke" :P

Comment: Same here. I don't see what would you want to fix here.

Comment: Yes I know it is not broken, I am asking how to improve the code. To me there looks to be a few duplicates that could be improved. e.g Do we need to getElementsByTagName 3 times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want less code, this solution should work:

```
function generateJs(){
    // Google Plus
    window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};
    $.getScript('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js');

    // Facebook
     $('body').append('<div id="fb-root"></div>');
    $.getScript('http://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId='+opt.faceBookID);

    // Twitter
    $.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js');
}
```

However, there is no way I see to speed up loading the scripts.

Comment: Perfect, this was all that I wanted.